# Animating travelled path in QGIS without temporal information and temporal controller

Tags: qgis, expression, time, geometry-generator, animation

In QGIS, I have a path (line layer) that I want to animate: it should succesively build up like showing a point marker that "drives" along the line and shows (unveils) the part of the total line covered so far. Like drawing the line with a point marker.

The problem, however, is that I do not have any temporal information. The path should just be drawn at a constant speed.

Using geometry generator, one can build the substring of a line using the function [`line_substring()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#line-substring). How to use this to create such an animated line?

Answer (score 3):

A great possibility to create animations in newer QGIS versions (since 3.26) without any temporal information is using the new [„Animation Settings“ option in the symbol widget’s Advanced menu](https://qgis.org/lt/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#feature-allow-any-symbol-to-be-an-animated-symbol):

[image]

1. To activate, in layer styling select the top symbol entry, go to <kbd>Advanced</kbd> > <kbd>Animation Settings...</kbd> and in the dialog that opens check the box <kbd>Is Animated</kbd> and set a Frame rate of e.g. 20 fps (frames per second). This affects how many different images are shown per second. A framerate of 1 fps will result in a "stuttering" image.
2. To create a dot representing the movement, create a new symbol layer of Geomtry Generator style and set Geometry type to Point. Then use the following expression. On line 3, you can change the value of `500`: lowering it will make the movement faster, increasing it will slow it down:

   ```
    with_variable(
        'speed',
        500, -- change speed: lower value=faster
        end_point(
            line_substring (
                $geometry,
                0,
                scale_linear(
                    @symbol_frame % @speed,
                    0, 
                    @speed-1,
                    0, 
                    length($geometry)
                )
            )
        )
    )
   ```
3. To create the line marking the already covered path, proceed the same way (don't forget to set Geometry type to `LineString`) with the same expression, but delete line 4 (`end_point(`) and the last line, the closing bracket `)`.

   **And here you are with your animation!**

   *By the way: The value showing the percentage of the covered path was created using an additional symbol layer of Font marker style. Instead of a fixed letter, I set <kbd>Character(s)</kbd> to data driven override with the expression `to_string(round((@symbol_frame%500)/5,0))  || '%'`. Use the same same value as `speed` above instead of `500` - or [rely on layer variables](http://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-pt-3-layer-level-variables/) to define a speed you can then use for all animated layers.*

#### Variant:

You can also create differnt effects like lightening the travelled path on a map:

[image]

To do so, proceed as follows: Use a background map (here: OpenStreetMap) and reduce its brightness. Then create a line layer as in step 3 above, but with a buffer around the line (change Geometry generator's geometry type to polygon) - see below for the slightly modified expression. When you have created the polygon like this, set it's color to a light gray. Finally, in the Layer Rendering section at the bottom, set <kbd>Blending Mode</kbd> to <kbd>Dodge</kbd> (or play around with different settings and colors for varying effects).

This is the expression to use:

```
 with_variable( 'speed', 500, -- change speed here
     buffer (
         line_substring (
             $geometry,
             0,
             scale_linear (@symbol_frame%@speed,0,@speed-1,0,length($geometry))
         ),
         10
     )
 )
```